# SMTP auth server settings

Tags: email, 4.2-jelly-bean, nexus-4, stock-email-app

I'm using my own SMTP server with SMTP AUTH for sending mails. The greeting looks like:

> 250-[...fqdn...] Hello [...fqdn...] [...ip...], pleased to meet you
>   250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
>   250-PIPELINING
>   250-8BITMIME
>   250-SIZE
>   250-DSN
>   250-AUTH CRAM-MD5 DIGEST-MD5
>   250-DELIVERBY
>   250 HELP

Unfortunately when configuring user name and password for SMTP (no TLS), Android 4.2 (the standard mail app of the Google/LG Nexus 4) does not seem to expect this: `authentication methods aren't supported by server`.

On the server, I see Android disconnecting after that greeting was sent.

What authentication methods are actually supported by Nexus 4's mail app?

Comment: I didn't look at the logs of my server for this, but I am using CRAM-MD5 myself with K9 mail. So it's definitely not the fault of Android, but rather of the mail app you're using. Maybe you could add information on your device, as different manufacturers might use different "stock email apps"?

Comment: @Izzy: It's the Google/LG Nexus 4. After your comment I tried K-9 and it is working. Thanks a lot. Adjusted question accordingly.

Comment: Glad the hint helped! So as suspected, it is a limitation of the pre-installed mail app of your device. Thanx for updating the details -- with some luck another GN4 user might be able to help on this.

Comment: Do you mind adding a few screenshots of your configuration window. In those, the text areas like username, password and server could left blank meanwhile keep other options as they were and take the screenshot.

Comment: @Murshid: It seems screenshots require rooting the phone which I did not do (yet?). However, the configuration for SMTP consists just of the following fields: server -- [...], port -- 587, security type -- none, require sign-in -- yes, username -- [...], password -- [...].

Comment: Did you give a try turning off require sign in?

Comment: @Murshid: Yes, then it just tries SMTP without authentication ... which is happily rejected by the server.

Comment: Well, it is kind of tough now. You have no problem with the port, since you are getting connected and you have no problem with android as well. So your server is rejecting the connection due to the authentication method. So your server isn't supporting CRAM-MD5 it seems. If you have an option to use PLAIN try it. You might have to install CRAM-MD5 authentication mechanism on your server.

Comment: The authentication **is** working on the server. It works with K-9 (with the same settings) and with different MTAs on PCs. It's just the stock email app which does not seem to play well.

Comment: Then it must be a bug in your stock app, as you have already doubted. We can't do much about it. I think you should try re-flashing the stock app

Answer (score 3):

Probably a bit late to the party, but I'm recording this here for posterity.  My wife's Xperia Z5 Compact (Android 5.?), as well as my own Samsung S3 (4.3) suffer from this same problem.  I've pulled down the source code to the most recent email client, and it appears that the only authentication mechanisms that the native email client supports is PLAIN, LOGIN and XOAUTH2, otherwise the client comes up with the above error message.  As noted in the OP, the mail server is only offering CRAM-MD5 and DIGEST-MD5, which the client doesn't support.  I had to add PLAIN and LOGIN to my mail server (after enforcing TLS), at which point the stock mail client was happy.